# Joomla 1.5 не могу добавить плагин в текст статьи

Tags: joomla, cms, плагин

Подключил плагин easypaypal, включил его в настройках, по гайду написано что бы добавило кнопку достаточно добавить в контент `{easypaypal}` но после добавления в тексте статьи просто выводится текст "{easypaypal}", вместо сгенерированой плагином кнопки. 
Попробовал добавить `{loadmodule <любой модуль>}`, результат тот же, хотя loadmodule включен в плагинах, с loadposition так же. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в выводе статьи:

- не будет компилировать:

  echo $this->article->introtext;
- Будет компилировать

  echo JHTML::_('content.prepare', $this->article->introtext);